# How do I prevent `any` values in a mapped type that fails complex inference through a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

[Link to playground with an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGkIgVAXigWACdkA7AcwCgaIAPMOU4KS4CUgMwEMBjaABFewXgB4aUKABUAgsDJoArp3yNOFACb54SNJhx4ANDQB8UAN5SopCLy1wK6EFFFLUqiAgD8ALlt7R2dXeUVyTzUAbQBdGzsHJxd2CmRgZF50ADVM5W9-KxtpBODkqJkjFNkFDy98ADIrAF8YgpJyahsmmm6aAHo%20qAB3AAsICih%20J3beSkoqKGAxqAA3XOhR8fZgAHJ8ACtlEjcoMHRZibhUfYh%20NgBabeGWAGsEOhpuZQo75CcoLSiCRhWpqKAacY6WCIFAYbC4BBmAAUgLEAREYnEIIidTMAEp0UCsTUcWoLNZihBgMpSBNUbwenQphRjnAXrxXER6UiKW5wio1AEojtuMhSCQAHK8AC2EB2MVM0jm6UyOXQeQQAV50lF4uAUtlAR2a3VcsV0jcVAgAQATFABlAAEoASQA4gAJGQAMQAqgAZKAAUUdjoA8o6uqYmni6A7IsMxhNmTM5tRFssTXkE1s0ntAtTaRAtKsMicvj90v9HmkAXBvBQdsA6OXfv96V7vvxifzIt5wQxNFC9LDDAjkfSAki8YQLBjgSSBd58ZPpwRZ0TsYvEYVKQW6UDGTRk2wKHBgKH2ZyAUCOz8kVOZ1AeTZ3KTvEKRWLJTK5QqbMqMmydZNR3C1dW-Q0oGNdYdnNaReCtW17UGABld1Q39IQgxDcMoAwmRIx6PE8SAA).

I have this complex interface that has 2 properties:

- An array of `attributes`
- A record of `initialValues`, where keys MUST be from the array of attributes (but not all of them, hence it should be partial)

```js
export interface Data<
  TAttributes extends string,
> {
  readonly attributes?: readonly TAttributes[]
  readonly initialValues?: {
    readonly [TKey in TAttributes & {}]?: string
  }
}
```

When my object is just a plain object, it works and I get an error when `initialValues` declares keys which are not part of `attributes`.

```js
function data<TAttributes extends string>(data: Data<TAttributes>): Data<TAttributes> {
  return data
}

const okay = data({
  attributes: ['firstName'],
  initialValues: {
    firstName: 'value',
    age: 2 // error here - which is correct
  },
})
```

But when my argument is actually a function that returns that kind of object (`Data`) - it doesn't. When adding a different attribute name which is not part of `attributes`, the inferred type of the extra property is `any` because of a weird failed inference.

```js
function dataFunc<TAttributes extends string>(data: () => Data<TAttributes>): () => Data<TAttributes> {
  return data
}

const notOkay = dataFunc(() => ({
  attributes: ['firstName'],
  initialValues: {
    firstName: 'value',
    age: 2 // should error out, but it doesn't
  },
}))
```

[image: example]

Is there a way to enforce this strictly either by:

- Exact keys in a partial record (I know this is not officially supported by TypeScript, but maybe there's a way to hack it for this particular use-case).
- Improving the inference on the function argument. I've tried doing it with the NoInfer trick but that failed.
- Disallowing `any` values in a record. Usually this is done via linting rules and the `typescript-eslint` plugin (e.g. `no-unsafe-return`), but there's no rule for object values. Also, I'd prefer to have this is a TypeScript check rather a lint check.

[Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGkIgVAXigWACdkA7AcwCgaIAPMOU4KS4CUgMwEMBjaABFewXgB4aUKABUAgsDJoArp3yNOFACb54SNJhx4ANDQB8UAN5SopCLy1wK6EFFFLUqiAgD8ALlt7R2dXeUVyTzUAbQBdGzsHJxd2CmRgZF50ADVM5W9-KxtpBODkqJkjFNkFDy98ADIrAF8YgpJyahsmmm6aAHo%20qAB3AAsICih%20J3beSkoqKGAxqAA3XOhR8fZgAHJ8ACtlEjcoMHRZibhUfYh%20NgBabeGWAGsEOhpuZQo75CcoLSiCRhWpqKAacY6WCIFAYbC4BBmAAUgLEAREYnEIIidTMAEp0UCsTUcWoLNZihBgMpSBNUbwenQphRjnAXrxXER6UiKW5wio1AEojtuMhSCQAHK8AC2EB2MVM0jm6UyOXQeQQAV50lF4uAUtlAR2a3VcsV0jcVAgAQATFABlAAEoASQA4gAJGQAMQAqgAZKAAUUdjoA8o6uqYmni6A7IsMxhNmTM5tRFssTXkE1s0ntAtTaRAtKsMicvj90v9HmkAXBvBQdsA6OXfv96V7vvxifzIt5wQxNFC9LDDAjkfSAki8YQLBjgSSBd58ZPpwRZ0TsYvEYVKQW6UDGTRk2wKHBgKH2ZyAUCOz8kVOZ1AeTZ3KTvEKRWLJTK5QqbMqMmydZNR3C1dW-Q0oGNdYdnNaReCtW17UGABld1Q39IQgxDcMoAwmRIx6PE8SAA).

Comment: Excess properties can only be discouraged, not prevented, so you might want to deal with this at runtime and not at compile time. But we can try to convince the compiler to care about your use case, possibly [like this](https://tsplay.dev/NB1OVw). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does work in my playground example indeed, but my actual use-case (which I thought I demonstrated well through it) doesn't work with such a solution. Especially considering the type I'm trying to constraint is deeply nested under lots of generic types. 

I've created a new playground with how the actual type nesting is demonstrated in my project: https://tsplay.dev/mpzBzw

Comment: ① What are you trying to convey with another being inferred as any? A property key name with no value in an object literal is a shorthand property, and if no variable exists named another then it's an error. Like const x = {y} when no variable named y exists: how exactly does this relate to your issue?

Comment: ② Looking at your new example, I translated my solution to [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjlvvm) and it looks like it works as well.  The error message isn't as pretty, but it's exactly the same thing, and we don't really have control over exactly how much of an offending expression the compiler underlines when it finds a mistake.  If that works for you, then if you don't mind I'd like to write up my answer to the question as originally asked, since the nesting doesn't seem to be changing anything fundamental and just serves to make the question/answer harder for future readers.

Comment: I conveyed the property key with no value since usually it helps me see what TS infers the value of.

Comment: But anyway - thanks for solving this! The error doesn't matter to me as long as it's an error. Go ahead and submit an official answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't really prohibit excess properties in general; object types are open and extendible, not closed or sealed (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  No matter what you do, nothing will prevent this from being allowed:

```
const a = { firstName: 'value', age: 2 }; // okay
const b: { firstName: string } = a; // okay
dataFunc(() => ({ attributes: ['firstName'], initialValues: b })) // okay
```

The best we can do in TypeScript is *discourage* excess properties.  The error you saw in your `okay` example for `data` is an example of [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), but that only kicks in for object literals directly assigned to a place that expects fewer properties. It doesn't work for function returns (see [microsoft/TypeScript#241](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241)), which is why you're not getting the error there.

If we want to emulate excess property checking in `dataFunc()`, we'll need to make it more [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to capture the full type of your `initialValues` property, and then [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) that type to one where the property type for any excess properties is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type):

```
type ExactAttributes<T, K extends PropertyKey> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? unknown : never
}   

function dataFunc<
  K extends string,
  T extends ExactAttributes<T, K>
>(data: () =>
  Data<K> & { initialValues?: T }): () => Data<K> {
  return data
}
```

Part of this is unchanged, you still have `K extends string` and `data`'s return type is still `Data<K>`, but now we are saying that it is *also* `{initValues?: T}` where `T` is constrained to `ExactAttributes<T, K>`.  If `T` is `{firstName: string, age: string}` and `K` is `"firstName"`, then `ExactAttributes<T, K>` is `{firstName: unknown, age: never}`. And therefore `T extends ExactActributes<T, K>` is not true, because `age` is of type `string` and not `never`.  Thus you'll get the desired error:

```
const notOkay = dataFunc(() => ({
  attributes: ['firstName'],
  initialValues: {
    firstName: 'value',
    age: 2 // error
    // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  }
}))
```

So, there you go, you've got something like excess property checking for function return types.  But remember, excess properties aren't really considered a type error, so the language doesn't really want to help you enforce such things.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAPAKGcgaWQgA9IQATAZ2SrClAHNkBeW+pgGhwD5kBvPMigQ4FAPYgANgE9kGDgCMArpCoB+AFzDRE6XIIBtALpCRYybOShgYYHCkA1B8ogbtg-PnN6rhgArWIITIAGQCAL7GWuwMIIxCEThJOGAyAA4oAKIkiGAAgmBKqm5YACqcIaTk1Mj+UOKZUGkEEDJ8bJ7IAUHIANZt4jDIZcbagdUQlDRE6sjKIH0g4gDuwdogEABu0Mk4ODALCHaSyBQYcABiR7j4RJPTsVxCZcRkU7U5eYXFauWVBB4vAAFOdMNpgQBKVhA-DoTBYQFhARBWz2JwuNwxV4RSEQ6EsPjw7BIroiMDKKDBMFwPY4BCSOjyVgomDAKB0ABycAAthBtAByLaYgWVOCMfnIABMyAiAG5kAB6RXIcR9OAyemMsDIRQeZBsjlgbl87R0OLMCIsuAK5Wq9WamnXEAIYFQmHIYH8eRFBgqNTaQwCw1c3kQAXGSo2OwOZxSVxUbSKWWQ6F2tUa-YMkBM5ZgADyDpZTqOboJfC9QgUfpKie6wfZob5Ee4+Gj6LjCY8QnwIeNYcFwvj4dbXnFkpldugDSgPaVKrKGRQApAyh5imgAusNDz8ioVGAjBAcEUUhQYHEyDSmWQK+2m4AdIlkqmgA)